# Is there a way to export the reading order in tagged PDF(Accessible PDF)?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to create a validation tool using the iText7, to compare the reading order and tagging order from the tagged PDF. Im new to iText.

I have used the below code in c# to extract the tagging structure and save it as xml.
Ref: ([Get marked content using the MCID content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45157963/get-marked-content-using-the-mcid-content/45162070#45162070))

```
    FileStream outXml = new FileStream("pdf_content.xml",FileMode.CreateNew);
    TaggedPdfReaderTool tool = new TaggedPdfReaderTool(pdfoc);
    tool.SetRootTag("root");
    tool.ConvertToXml(outXml);
    outXml.Close();
```

I expect to export the reading order to Xml or other format.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Reading order is a human concept, and might be different from person to person.

Have a look at the following example:

[image: magazine article]

The red parts are snippets that are relevant to the story, but they break the normal layout.

- Do you read them first?
- Do you read them as you are passing them in top to bottom, left-to-right reading order?
- Do you read them last?

Reading order (in the general case) needs human verification at least.

Comment: I'm asking about the reading order in acrobat PDF document, May be this videos will help, we can tag the reading order in PDF. After completing the tagging structure i have to do some validation, for that i have to extract the tags from reading pane and tag pane.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KP5gfrdhLVs

Comment: For your information it is already a tagged PDF with proper reading order, I want to extract those text to validate them.